# Populating a HTML table column wise

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

From the questions that have been previously asked most of them have answered apparently no for the question. But I suppose there should be a way I could populate the HTML table the desired way.

I am having a HTML table which i was able to make it populate row wise, but I want to eliminate the duplication of the name of the attributes being displayed.

I have the code that works in the row wise population and the resulting output. I have tried the same column wise, but I cant see where I could populate the Values.

The values in the table are being populated from the database.

Code that populates the table row wise.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Option Value</th>
        <th colspan="3">Set Value</th>
        @*<th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>*@
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.OptionValues)
    {
        //var row = @item.SetValue.Count + 1;
        if (item.SetValue.Count == 0)
        {   @:<tr>
            @:<td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Optionvalues", new { id = item.OptionValueID},null)</td>
            @:<td>@item.OptionVal</td>
            @:<td></td>
            @:</tr> 
    }
        int count = 0;
    if(item.SetValue.Count!=0)
    {
        @:<tr>
            @:<td rowspan="@item.SetValue.Count">@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Optionvalues", new { id = item.OptionValueID},null)</td>
            @:<td rowspan="@item.SetValue.Count">@item.OptionVal</td>

            foreach(var set in item.SetValue)
            {
                if (count ==0)
                {
                @:<td>@set.TcSet.SetName</td>
                @:<td>@set.Value</td>
                @:<td>@set.Status</td>
                @:<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "SetValues", new { id = set.SetValueID },null)</td>
                @:</tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    @:<tr>
                    @:<td>@set.TcSet.SetName</td>
                    @:<td> @set.Value</td>
                    @:<td>@set.Status</td>
                    @:<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "SetValues", new { id = set.SetValueID },null)</td>
                }
                count++;

            }
            }
         @:</tr>
    } 
</table>
```

Output of the resulting table

[image: Table being populated row wise]

**Expected output**

[image: Expected Output]

I could populate the first column with the Property names. But I do not know how I could populate the values in the next column.

I tried a foreach loop but I will not be able to populate the values column wise though.

Any work around for the the task in hand?

**Update**

Based on Suggestion from @Nick , I have tried the following

```
 @foreach(var ov in Model.OptionValues)
 {
 <div class="col">@ov.OptionVal</div>
 foreach(var s in ov.SetValue)
 {
    <div class="row">@s.Value</div>
 }
 }
```

Comment: I will try updating my question with a code that is near to the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Do you HAVE to use table layout? 
You can simply use block elements and align them table-like with css columns or css flex box;

So:

```
`@foreach (var i in Model)
    {
div.column
 @foreach (var set in i)
    {
   div.row-in-col
    } 
}`
```

and then in css something like

```
`.element-that-contains-columns{
 display:flex;
}
.row-in-col {
height : @some-fixed-height;
}`
```

Which will result in something like this:

```css
.container{display:flex}
.row{
  height:30px;
  padding:4px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col">
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col">
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
  <div class="row">Lorem</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give me 5 mins to try it out. It isnt necessary that i have to use the table layout. I tried with div and was doing it wrong. so i had to stick on to tables

Comment: I am sorry, what is the working behind the for loop? i add a `div column`? And `row in col`. May be i get a better idea after trying it in my code. just was curious before doing

Comment: sorry i couldnt find a class in div called `row-in-col`

Comment: LOL, sorry. It's Zen coding shortcut for 
<div class="column"> </div> and <div class="row"> </div>
So in columns there's the second loop for rows. Like in your code.

Comment: i get it all line by line. i will update the question with your suggestion. please check if this was what you tried to convey.

Comment: `@foreach(var ov in Model.OptionValues)
 {
 <div class="col">
@ov.OptionVal
 foreach(var s in ov.SetValue)
 {
    <div class="row">@s.Value</div>
 }
</div>

 }
`

Comment: Difference is that rows must be populated inside the column :)

Comment: I have also added the same. Am i missing something in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92518/discussion-between-nick-panov-and-vini-vasundharan).